# Updating URL on ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, call

Trying to update url whenever the button for modal to show content is clicked, managed to find out how to change it but it returns http://localhost:3000/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

which is not what I want, I want the normal blog post slug after my domain, any way I can achieve that dynamically? I'm using wordpress for this.

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, this.url);
```

Whole ajax.js

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('body').on('click', '.view-post', function() {
        var data = {
            'action': 'load_post_by_ajax',
            'id': $(this).data('id'),
            'security': blog.security
        };
 
        $.post(blog.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            response = JSON.parse(response);
            $('#postModal h5#postModalLabel').text(response.title);
            $('#postModal .modal-body').html(response.content);
 
            var postModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('postModal'));
            postModal.show();

            window.history.pushState(null, null, this.url);

            
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution, so you have to store slug name in your callback function like this.

```
        // Get the post ID or some way to retrieve the post slug
        $post_id = get_the_ID(); // Example: Assuming you're inside a loop

        // Get the post slug
        $post_slug = get_post_field('post_name', $post_id);
        
        $arr_response = array(
            'title' => get_the_title(),
            'content' => get_the_content(),
            'post_slug' => $post_slug,
        );

echo json_encode($arr_response);
```

inside ajax js file you can extract post_slug and store it in the variable

```
        $.post(blog.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            response = JSON.parse(response);
            var postSlug = response.post_slug;


window.history.pushState(null, null, postSlug);
```